# variable in function changes when it goes from HTML to JS

Tags: ajax, laravel, variables, dynamic

[image]

[image]

So I'm building this jquery bootstrap table inside a model in laravel and as you can see it comes up with the same numbers but when you click on it and send it to the function the number comes up 1 minus the original number.  Any ideas?

Here is the controller:

```
        if($data) {
        for ($i = 0; $i<sizeof($data['data']); $i++) {
            $adsetid = $data['data'][$i]['adset_id'];
            $link = strval($adsetid);
           // dd($link);  
            if (!array_key_exists('actions', $data['data'][$i])) {
                $summary[$i] = array('results' => intval('0').' Leads',
                'cpr' => '$'.intval('0'),
                'reach' => intval($data['data'][$i]['reach']),
                'impressions' => intval($data['data'][$i]['impressions']),
                'spend' => "$".round(floatval($data['data'][$i]['spend']),2),
                'ctr' => round($data['data'][$i]['ctr'],6),
                'cpc' => round($data['data'][$i]['cpc'],6),
                'clicks' => intval($data['data'][$i]['clicks']),
                'account_id' => intval($data['data'][$i]['account_id']),
                'account_name' => $data['data'][$i]['account_name'],
                'adset_id' => '<a href="#" onclick="adminAjaxCall('.($link).')">'.intval($data['data'][$i]['adset_id']).'</a>',
                'ad_name' => $data['data'][$i]['ad_name'],
                'campaign_id' => intval($data['data'][$i]['campaign_id']),
                'campaign_name' => $data['data'][$i]['campaign_name']);
            }
```

and the javscript:

```
function adminAjaxCall(value) {
console.log(value);
$("#high_charts_admin").hide();
$("#load").show();
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/facebookadmin/',
    data: {
        adsetId: value
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
        $('#load').hide();
        $("#high_charts_admin").show();
        console.log("adminAjaxCallSuccess:");
        console.log(response);
        adminDrawHighCharts(response);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { // What to do if we fail
        console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
        console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

}

Comment: You're going to have to show your javascript and controller.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I was hoping someone might just have a broad generalization of it, but below is my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not completely sure why it just reduces it by one, but I tried simply opening developer tools and assigning that number to a var with `a = 23842710141990585` and it did the same. The `a` var is then 23842710141990584.

Turns out this number is far larger than Javascript's [`MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER).

I suggest you cast it to a string instead.

You need to wrap the `$link` in quotes, which will cast it to a string, like @manian pointed out:

`'adset_id' => '<a href="#" onclick="adminAjaxCall(\''.$link.'\')">'.intval($data['data'][$i]['adset_id']).'</a>'`

Edit, to answer the comment of what `\` does:

It [escapes the next character](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single). Since the string you posted is wrapped in single quotes, adding a single quote within the string would naturally end it. So in order to actually print the single quote, you prefix it with a backslash: `\'`.

In your case, you needed to turn the number in `adminAjaxCall(123)` into a string. You do this by adding single or double quotes around the number: `adminAjaxCall('123')`. And that's what we accomplished - added single quotes around the number.

Comment: that's the thing, in the php controller I have done a dd(gettype()) and it's a string.  Somewhere between there and the ajax it turns to a number because a simple console.log(typeof ) shows that its now a number.  I am jsut not sure where the change took place.

Comment: Can you post the view code that prints the `onClick="adminAjaxCall(...)"`? Chances are you just need to wrap the ID in quotes: `'id'`.

Comment: please try to change the code like this & check if its working, `'adset_id' => '<a href="#" onclick="adminAjaxCall(\''.$link.'\')">'.intval($data['data'][$i]['adset_id']).'</a>',`

Comment: Oh yeah, it gets printed in the controller, I didn't see earlier. What manian suggested should work.

Comment: manian you are a genius.  I don't know why I didnt think of that.  Works perfeclty.  Thank you so much

Comment: I am glad that it worked.@devk was the one who found its a type casting issue. @devk, can you please update this answer so that it will be useful to others

Comment: So I'm new to coding/programming, can someone explain in a little more detail what \ does?  Instead of being a copy/paster I want to really learn this.  Thanks

Comment: It escapes the next character. I've edited my answer.